# React Native Fetch API returning text with escape characters

Tags: react-native, navigation, fetch, react-navigation

I am a developing a React Native app and fetching API for login.Below is my store where I am calling API.

auth.js:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async- 
 storage';
import Device from '../../model/Device';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';


export const LOGIN ='LOGIN';


export const login=(textemailid,textpassword) =>{
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('txtUemail',textemailid);
formData.append('txtUpass',textpassword);
return async dispatch =>{
 await fetch('https:------/login.php',
{
  method:'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
},
  body: formData
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(
  (loginr) =>{
 var loginresult = 
 loginr.replace('\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t','');
 console.log(loginresult);
 if(loginresult === 'success')
 {
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'Home'
  });
  
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
 }
 else if(loginresult === 'Login Status'){
  {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'Auth'
    });
    
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
   }
 }
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  }) 
  dispatch({type:LOGIN});
  }
  }
```

The API returns text data instead of JSON.Since I dont have access to API,I have used .replace to remove escape characters.
I am getting the output as 'success' (for correct username password) and 'Login Failed' (for incorrect username password)
Now I want to navigate to Home page if 'success' and Auth page if 'Login Failed'.I have used react-navigation for navigation but its not navigating and I am not getting an error.Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The API PHP program was not written by me.But in the php they have echoed means its string.In postman its not json output. If I pick json the result is same as one(with escape characters) in above screenshot.Cant we remove the escape characters and use the result as string "success"?

Comment: The problem is not on your react code but from the API  , if you haven't access to edit the API .. just maintain it as plain Text and us some JS lib to split or remove  space and the "success" text .. after tht  parse it to JSON ...

For exemple try to use this lib or other  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-manipulation

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I used .replace to fetch the correct output.I am trying to navigate to Home page now.